# Getting Site temporarily unavailable. Connection timed out - please try again. when submitting FreeForm Form

Tags: solspace-freeform, error

Get the Error message:

> Site temporarily unavailable.
>   Connection timed out - please try again.

when submitting FreeForm Form.

The Form data is getting correctly into the table `exp_freeform_entries`. It is not sending email notifications.

Not sure what is causing this.
It would be nice to know what file is performing the action on the form.

Comment: Have you looked in your error log files? Sounds like a time out error as you're scripts don't have enough time to run completely.

Comment: The timeout could be caused by problems sending emails. The data is being submitted and updated, but you're not receiving mails. As you have notifications turned on (I'm guessing, as you're waiting on emails), if there's a problem sending mails, then the process hasn't completed and so you're getting a timeout error, rather than the return page. Can you verify that you can send mails via the Communicate option in Expression Engine? **Tools > Communicate** . If you can't send/receive mails this way, then this could be where the problem lies.